# Procedimiento almacenado en MySql sin parametros

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Tengo una duda hace un tiempo y ahora lo necesito, ya intente de varias maneras y con busquedas en google pero aun no lo logro.
Necesito crear varios procedimientos almacenados pero sin parametros

esta es la manera en que lo hecho pero no me funciona

```
select * from usuarios


DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE Us_ListUsuarios
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Us_Id, Us_nombres, Us_Apellidos, Us_Telefono, Us_Correo, IdRol, IdArea FROM usuarios;
END $$
```

Comment: Y como es que no funciona? No regresa valores?

Comment: Te sale algun error al ejecutarlo? Podrias anexar el resultado

Comment: Ya pude, tenia que quitar el ``` as ``` y añadir ``` () ``` despues del nombre del procedure

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso solo agrege () y saque el AS y el END, aqui seria un ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que les sirva.